# Dynamically retrieve field from JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON:

```
let myJson = 
{
    'name':'John Doe'
    'address': {
        'country':'CN'
        'city':'Toronto'
    }
}
```

I can select the values by

```
console.log(myJson['name'])
console.log(myJson['address']['country'])
```

I'm trying to do it this way

```
function getValue(key) {
    console.log(myJson[key]);
}

//this works
getValue('name');
```

I can get the `name` value but how do I get the nested ones with the function above?

Comment: How about :
`function getValue(key1.key2) {
    console.log(myJson[key1][key2]);
}`

Comment: `getValue(getValue(obj,'address'),'country')`

Comment: Lodash has a [handy method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) for this... `_.get(myJson, 'address.country')`